# Keycloak 17: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession and qualifiers [@Default]

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

We are using keycloak as IDP and have some custom plugins/Spi, we are in process of  updating our keycloak instance to version 17 Quarkas distribution and the SPIs began to break (error below) during keycloak build process. I've made sure that there are no keycloak libraries packed as part of jar.

The SPI looks like below and have corresponding entries in Manifest file under Manifest/services/org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory

Custom SPI/plugin

```
public class SwaggerJsonRetrieverFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {
    @Override
    public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new SwaggerJsonRetriever(session);
    }


    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {

    }


    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {

    }


    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "swagger.json";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like below

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-dataformat-yaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

The error which I'm getting

```
 io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems: 
[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.abc.swagger.SwaggerJsonRetriever().session
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.abc.swagger.SwaggerJsonRetriever, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.abc.swagger.SwaggerJsonRetriever]
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession and qualifiers [@Default]
```

Is there any configuration which I'm missing, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed issues with our resource providers after migration as well(JBoss -> Quarkus). They don't seem to get picked up out of the META-INF/services definitions. I've had to adjust our plugin quite a bit to even get it to load under Quarkus. Ended up removing all the JBoss libraries and migrated to the quarkus versions. Still dealing with this issue though. I'll share if I figure out what's causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I've faced same, all external libraries need to be bundled with fat jar and make sure to exclude keycloak libraries as well as they will be loaded from `keycloak/lib/lib/main` folder, the only thing which is blocking me at the moment is during build it's complaining about unsatisfied dependency with Provider despite for fact I'm initializing the `KeycloakSession` in `RealmResourceProvider` constructor passed from `RealmResourceProviderFactory`

Comment: Figured out what my issue was, in my case. It was just a context path issue. I was referencing the wrong base path in my curl command. However, regarding your issue. It sounds like the "Default" annotation used in your SwaggerJsonRetriever isn't getting resolved in the classpath after deploy. Drill down the annotation and see what library it's defined in and make sure that library is included in your maven  pom dependencies.

Comment: There is no default annotation used in my `RealmResourceProvider` class which is `SwaggerJsonRetriever`, the keycloak build is complaining because it cannot inject KeycloakSession via `RealmResourceProviderFactory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove @Path annotation from class.